# Security breach in the UK - who to report

Tags: security

I came across a company in the UK (I was just a consumer) whereby they were handling sensitive information in an insecure way.  Who would be the best people to notify about problems with security?

Comment: Is the website providing any "contact us" page ?

Comment: Your question might be better suited for https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Personally, I think this could live in superuser as it is more to do with the use of software rather than a security professional question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first port of call should be to notify the company themselves - they may not realise and it may be a genuine mistake. This would give them the opportunity to rectify the problem, which is the best outcome.

If they have no contact information on their website and they are a limited company, you can try to find their details from [Companies House](https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-a-company), though it will likely only provide postal address information.

If you still have concerns you could try contacting the [Information Commissioner's Office](https://ico.org.uk/) which handles failures to comply with Data Protection legislation.